# Android Doesn't receive message from server

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets, server

I am trying to do a chat between clients in java. my server is in python. it works well. my clients are able to send messages to the server but they are not receiving data from the server.

my clients code is this:

```
package com.example.serverapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Thread Thread1 = null;
    EditText etIP, etPort;
    TextView tvMessages;
    EditText etMessage;
    Button btnSend;
    String SERVER_IP;
    int SERVER_PORT;
    String connect = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        etIP = findViewById(R.id.etIP);
        etIP.setText("10.0.0.18");
        etPort = findViewById(R.id.etPort);
        etPort.setText(String.valueOf(7272));
        tvMessages = findViewById(R.id.tvMessages);
        etMessage = findViewById(R.id.etMessage);
        btnSend = findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
        Button btnConnect = findViewById(R.id.btnConnect);
        btnConnect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                connect = etMessage.getText().toString();
                etMessage.setText("");
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, connect, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                tvMessages.setText("");
                SERVER_IP = etIP.getText().toString().trim();
                SERVER_PORT = Integer.parseInt(etPort.getText().toString().trim());
                Thread1 = new Thread(new Thread1());
                Thread1.start();
            }
        });
        btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String message = etMessage.getText().toString().trim();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (!message.isEmpty()) {
                    new Thread(new Thread3(message)).start();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private PrintWriter output;
    private BufferedReader input;

    class Thread1 implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            Socket socket;
            try {
                socket = new Socket(SERVER_IP, SERVER_PORT);
                output = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());

                output.write(connect);
                output.flush();

                input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        tvMessages.setText("Connected\n");
                    }
                });
                new Thread(new Thread2()).start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    class Thread2 implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    final String message = input.readLine();

                    if (message != null) {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                tvMessages.append("server: " + message + "\n");
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        Thread1 = new Thread(new Thread1());
                        Thread1.start();
                        return;
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    class Thread3 implements Runnable {
        private String message;
        Thread3(String message) {
            this.message = message;
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {

            output.write(message);
            output.flush();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    tvMessages.append("client: " + message + "\n");
                    etMessage.setText("");
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The thread that receives messages is thread 2.
I don't find any problems in the code but it doesn't receive any data.

Comment: `final String message = input.readLine();` The client tries to read a line and will wait until the server sent a line. Now did the server send a line? A line is a text message ending on \n. So `String messagetosend = "Hello dear client.\n";`

Comment: That was my problem. I forgot to add the \n